# In rxjs how can I create groups of sequential values?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-streams

I have a stream of values in this form:

```
[1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,2...]
```

I would like to convert it to a stream of groups in the form:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[1],[1,2]...]
```

New group should be created every time value becomes 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [bufferWhen()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/bufferwhen.html) operator to collect emitted values until an observable emits a value. In this example I use a subject to emit a shallow copy of the stream to the buffer.

The buffer will emit when ever the number `1` is emitted. If the stream starts with `1` then an empty array is emitted. So I filter that away.

```js
const {from, Subject} = rxjs;
const {filter, bufferWhen, tap, skip} = rxjs.operators;

const stream = from([1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,2]);
const trigger = new Subject();

stream.pipe(
   tap(v => trigger.next(v)),
   bufferWhen(() => trigger.pipe(filter(v => v === 1))),
   filter(v => v.length)
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.x/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

You can use the [scan()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) if you wanted to emit the trigger when the value *decreases* from the previous. Which is maybe a little better in logic, but using `1` as the trigger fits with the question.

Comment: Works fine! I couldn't have figured out such a solution :)  . Nice also using filter instead of `skip(1)` in case array starts from other than `1`

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I'm posting a solution alternative to the accepted answer.

NOTE: For finite streams `concat(of(1))` is required before `scan()`, for `distinctUntilChanged` to emit the last observable.

```js
const {of, from, ReplaySubject} = rxjs;
const {map, concat, scan, distinctUntilChanged, concatAll, toArray, delay} = rxjs.operators;

//considering infinite stream
const stream = from([1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,2]);
stream.pipe(
    scan( (acc, val) => {
        if(val===1){
            acc.complete()
            acc=new ReplaySubject();
        }
        acc.next(val);
        return acc;
    }, new ReplaySubject()), 
    distinctUntilChanged(), 
    map(toArray()), 
    concatAll() );
```

It would be nice to collect some feedback regarding preferred solution.